# How to use DAO from different contexts, where eager initialisation is not always required?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, dao

Suppose we have Java EE/Spring application, with DAO and eventualy @Service objects providing data to controller.

We construct DAO/Service method to get whole needed data for controller/presentation layer in two concerns:

- which data to take (criteria, where queries, limiting count etc.)
- what data to take (lazy/eager fetching)

Now we can have at least 2 scenerios, for almost the same methods:

1. get data where X (it can be complicated condition/logic), but provide only simple data (Lazy initialization gives that)
2. get data where X (the same conditions/logic as above), but provide full initializet entity with collection etc (eager initialization gives that).

Because controller has object in detached state, it cannot initialize "lazy part" - we already make the decision by defining fetch type or in DAO method query.

**lazy initialisation resolves problem 1., but when we have situation no 2. it forces us to duplicate condition logic in another DAO/Service method** or to create methods like:

`getClientsFromLastMonthWithoutAddresInfo()`
`getClientsFromLastMonthWithAddresInfo()`
`getClientsFromLastMonthWithAddressInfoAndPersonalData()`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the new JPA 2.1 fetch plans?

Comment: The Open Session In View pattern is a possibility https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView but many consider it an antipattern

Comment: I'm searching for alternative. I think that is just to heavy solution for such low-level problem.

Comment: how do you tell your service/data layer whether you want eager or lazy initialization?